# Convert image on disk to MSSQL image datatype

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I have images on the disk on web server and I want to write a script in classic asp (vbscript) that would take image and save it in MSSQL (2005) database (image datatype column). The SQL database is on a different server

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help. I think I figured out how to do this in classic ASP

```
strFilePath = Server.MapPath("your file")

Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With oConn 
.connectiontimeout = 0
.commandtimeout = 0
.connectionstring = <your connection string>
.cursorlocation = 3 'adUseClient
.open
End With

Set oStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
oStream.Type = 1 'AdBinary
oStream.Open
oStream.LoadFromFile strFilePath
xBin = oStream.Read

Set oCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
oCmd.ActiveConnection = oConn
strSql = "INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (strImage) VALUES(?);"
oCmd.CommandText = strSql
oCmd.Parameters.Item(0) = xBin
Set oRs = oCmd.Execute
Set oRs = Nothing
Set oStream = Nothing
Set oConn = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL image datatype is "byte[]" array

```
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes("Path to file");
```

now use this buffer to insert into MSSQL table image column

now MSSQL command will be like this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO <your_table_name> (ImageColumn) values (@parameter)");
cmd.Parameters.AdWithValues("@parameter",buffer);
```

Comment: Could you please provide me an example how I can achieve the same in classic asp.